# SVG Animation Compatibility in Microsoft Edge

Tags: svg, microsoft-edge

So I've been trying to make my svg animation compatible with Microsoft Edge but haven't gotten anywhere. So far the animation works fluidly on Chrome and Firefox.

Someone suggested that I add "px" to stroke-dashoffset but it does not work. Any help or suggestions are greatly appreciated.

SVG Animation: https://codepen.io/seungryul93/pen/zVKmMQ

```html
<svg version="1.1" id="preloader-svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 106.8 54" style="enable-background:new 0 0 106.8 54;" xml:space="preserve">
<style type="text/css">
 .st0{clip-path:url(#SVGID_2_);}
 .st1{fill:none;stroke:#c5c5c5;stroke-width:12.1;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
 .st2{clip-path:url(#SVGID_4_);}
 .st3{fill:none;stroke:#4960b4;stroke-width:12.1;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
 .st4{clip-path:url(#SVGID_6_);}
 .st5{fill:none;stroke:#c5c5c5;stroke-width:14;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
 .st6{clip-path:url(#SVGID_8_);}
 .st7{fill:none;stroke:#4960b4;stroke-width:14;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-miterlimit:10;}

 #preloader-svg {
  display:block;
  max-width: 20em;
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
 }

 @keyframes offset_one {

  24% {

   stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }

  100% {

   stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
 }

 .sub_one polyline,
 .sub_two polyline {

  stroke-dasharray: 140;
  stroke-dashoffset: 140;
  animation: offset_one 5s linear infinite;
 }

 @keyframes offset_two {

  12% {

   stroke-dashoffset: 150;
  }

  42% {

   stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }

  100% {

   stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
 }

 .sub_four polyline,
 .sub_three polyline {

  stroke-dasharray: 150;
  stroke-dashoffset: 150;
  animation: offset_two 5s linear infinite;
 }

    @keyframes fade_out {

     80% {

      opacity: 1;
     }

     95% {

      opacity: 0;
     }

     100% {

      opacity: 0;
     }
    }

    .feat {

     animation: fade_out 5s linear infinite;
    }
</style>
<g class="feat">
<g>
    <g>
  <defs>
   <path id="SVGID_1_" d="M90.5,22.3H42.9l2.8-3.3l5.2-6.1V19h11.7V0H45.8L0,53.8h16.1L32.9,34h56.9c2.1,0,3.8,1.7,3.8,3.8c0,0,0,0,0,0    l0,0c0,2.4-2,4.4-4.4,4.4l0,0l0,0c-2.4,0-4.4-2-4.4-4.4v0v-1h-1.5H71.8v0.6c0,9.1,7.4,16.6,16.6,16.6h2.5    c8.7,0,15.8-7.1,15.8-15.8c0-0.3,0-0.5,0-0.8C106.3,28.9,99,22.3,90.5,22.3z"/>
     </defs>
     <clipPath id="SVGID_2_">
      <use xlink:href="#SVGID_1_"  style="overflow:visible;"/>
     </clipPath>
 </g>
 <g class="st0 sub_one">
  <polyline class="st1" points="3.4,59.3 51.3,2.8 57.1,2.8 57,55 "/>
 </g>
</g>
<g>
    <g>
  <defs>
   <polygon id="SVGID_3_" points="50.9,54 62.6,54 62.6,36.8 50.9,36.8   "/>
     </defs>
     <clipPath id="SVGID_4_">
      <use xlink:href="#SVGID_3_"  style="overflow:visible;"/>
     </clipPath>
 </g>
 <g class="st2 sub_two">
  <polyline class="st3" points="3.4,59.3 51.3,2.8 57.1,2.8 57,55 "/>
 </g>
</g>
<g>
    <g>
  <defs>
   <path id="SVGID_5_" d="M90.5,22.3H42.9l2.8-3.3l5.2-6.1V19h11.7V0H45.8L0,53.8h16.1L32.9,34h56.9c2.1,0,3.8,1.7,3.8,3.8c0,0,0,0,0,0    l0,0c0,2.4-2,4.4-4.4,4.4l0,0l0,0c-2.4,0-4.4-2-4.4-4.4v0v-1h-1.5H71.8v0.6c0,9.1,7.4,16.6,16.6,16.6h2.5    c8.7,0,15.8-7.1,15.8-15.8c0-0.3,0-0.5,0-0.8C106.3,28.9,99,22.3,90.5,22.3z"/>
     </defs>
     <clipPath id="SVGID_6_">
      <use xlink:href="#SVGID_5_"  style="overflow:visible;"/>
     </clipPath>
 </g>
 <g class="st4 sub_three">
        <polyline class="st5" points="30.7,28.2 86.6,28.2 93.8,28.8 97.2,30.9 99.8,34.1 100.4,39.1 98.7,43.7 96.7,47 94.9,47.4 90.9,48 
     85.9,47.7 82.3,45.8 79.5,43.5 78.1,38.3 77.8,34.7 77.8,24.5 77.8,-0.3 "/>
 </g>
</g>
<g>
    <g>
  <defs>
   <rect id="SVGID_7_" x="71.8" y="0" width="11.5" height="19"/>
     </defs>
     <clipPath id="SVGID_8_">
      <use xlink:href="#SVGID_7_"  style="overflow:visible;"/>
     </clipPath>
 </g>
 <g class="st6 sub_four">
  <polyline class="st7" points="35.3,28.2 86.6,28.2 93.8,28.8 97.2,30.9 99.8,34.1 100.4,39.1 98.7,43.7 96.7,47 94.9,47.4 90.9,48 
     85.9,47.7 82.3,45.8 79.5,43.5 78.1,38.3 77.8,34.7 77.8,24.5 77.8,-0.3 "/>
 </g>
</g>
</g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is related to the .st5 class style. Try to add the "stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;" style in this class.

Code as below:

```
.st5 {
    fill: none;
    stroke: #c5c5c5;
    stroke-width: 14;
    stroke-linecap: round;
    stroke-linejoin: round;
    stroke-miterlimit: 10;
}
```

The result like this (using Microsoft Edge 44):

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the help!

However, it seems that when I make the proposed fix, the st5 class appears too early before it animation start time.